# Javascript - Dispatch event to all objects in a set

Tags: javascript, set, konvajs, event-dispatching, for-of-loop

How do I dispatch a custom event to all the custom objects in my set?

```
class Node{...}

a = new Node(...);
b = new Node(...);

var nodeSet = new Set(...);
let myEvent = new CustomEvent(...);

for (var node of nodeSet){
     node.shape.dispatchEvent(myEvent); 
}
```

Node.shape is a [Konva](https://konvajs.org/) Shape

Please keep the replies easy to understand since I am a beginner in Javascript, thanks.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I gave 'Event Recipient object javscript' a quick google search but I couldn't find anything that I understood. Could you care to expand?

Comment: I wasn't clear- I've answered with one of the solutions below.

Comment: Ahh I see, I will give it a go and let you know. I considered this earlier but thought it was a bit bodgy, nevertheless a solution is still a solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: I made an edit to ensure each `node` object is recognized. I bound the event handler to the instance.

Comment: If you don't like dispatching to the element, you could always dispatch it to the `document`, but then it's dispatched throughout the eventing phases.

Answer (score 1):

To make your custom event work with *Konva* `Node` objects, the `Shape` subclass has an `on` method that will allow you to register your listener directly on the shape.

Do this:

```js
class Node{...}

a = new Node(...);
b = new Node(...);
a.shape.on('Yo!', handler);
b.share.on('Yo!', handler);
  // all 4000 shapes

var nodeSet = new Set(...);
let myEvent = new CustomEvent('Yo!');

// If you only have one handler for every shape's treatment of CustomEvent
for (var node of nodeSet){
     node.shape.on('Yo!', handler);
}

for (var node of nodeSet){
     node.shape.dispatchEvent(myEvent); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am still going to leave this question open for a while, to let other suggestions come in.

Comment: That's cool. Glad to help. What variations would you be seeking?

Comment: I would prefer not to create a new div but other than that, it is a very elegant solution, now that I see it in code, thanks!

Comment: I just changed it from a `div` to an `EventTarget` for you - works. the same way.

Comment: I think you'll find that any other solution will require dispatching the event to the document or to each individual node.

Comment: Ok thank you for the follow up. I am just a bit confused about the .bind(this). I dont really understand how it acts as a function and how could I pass the event through the shaper method? Edit: I did some research and used this.shaper.bind(this, event). My question is, how did the event get passed on?

Comment: Ok, I caved - I went looked at the docs. Here is your solution (as terrible as it is). You're bound  to the API unless those classes are extensible. Then you can do it the other way.